# Make part of the text as readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make the part of the strings as read only.

Ex:

Name: SS,KS,MM,LL,PP

In this name text I want to make KS and LL as read only using javascript or jquery.

Can anyone suggest how can I implement this functionality?

Comment: `<input type="text"/><input type="text" value="KS" readonly="readonly"/><input type="text">`

Comment: These all text(SS,KS,MM,LL,PP) are in one textbox.

Comment: Make one textbox for each string

Comment: The person who downvoted this question please tell me the reason why did you downloaded it. It is useless downvote without telling the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make part of a textbox readonly.
However, you can try to add a pattern to the textbox. With the correct pattern logic you may be able to do what you want.

You can find many jQuery plugin for textbox with pattern. For instance:
http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-mask-input-plugin/